# can't get the second javascript function to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, url

i can't get second javascript function to work.
when i click 'Send Mail' button it should call the second function and pass it these two values. 
the href line (second last line in first function) is not rendered correctly.

```
<script>
function getvals(first,second) {
    alert(''+first+'');
    alert(''+second+'');
    mywindow=window.open('','Send Mail','height=200,width=400');
    mywindow.document.write("<FORM NAME='test'>");
    mywindow.document.write("<table align='center'><tr><td>User/Group: </td><td><input type='text' id='newfirst' name='iuser'></td></tr>");
    mywindow.document.test.iuser.value = ''+first+'';
    mywindow.document.write("<tr><td>Issue Key: </td><td><input type='text' id='newsecond' name='ikey'></td></tr>");
    mywindow.document.test.ikey.value = ''+second+'';
    mywindow.document.write("<tr><td><a href='javascript:popitup(document.getElementById('newuser').value,document.getElementById('newkey').value);'>Send Mail</a></td></tr></table>");
    mywindow.document.write("</FORM>");
}
function popitup(user,key) {
    alert(''+user+'');
    alert(''+key+'');
    var url = 'http:\/\/localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/mailservlet?receiver=' + user + '&issue=' + key;
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=400,width=400');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should consider using modern JavaScript. That looks like it's from the 1990's and it has more problems with it that I can count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `popitup` will not be called as it is written in the parent window, not in the window opened by `window.open`. Try `window.opener` in your function call.

Answer (score 1):

Nested quotes problem, you sould correctly escape it:

```
 mywindow.document.write("<tr><td><a href='javascript:popitup(document.getElementById(\"newuser\").value,document.getElementById(\"newkey\").value);'>Send Mail</a></td></tr></table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

[See it working](http://jsbin.com/ufomox/2/watch)

```
  function getvals(first,second) {
      alert(''+first+'');
      alert(''+second+'');
      mywindow=window.open('','Send Mail','height=200,width=400');
      mywindow.document.write("<FORM NAME='test'>");
      mywindow.document.write("<table align='center'><tr><td>User/Group: </td><td><input type='text' id='newfirst' name='iuser'></td></tr>");
      mywindow.document.test.iuser.value = ''+first+'';
      mywindow.document.write("<tr><td>Issue Key: </td><td><input type='text' id='newsecond' name='ikey'></td></tr>");
      mywindow.document.test.ikey.value = ''+second+'';
      mywindow.document.write("<tr><td><a href=\"javascript:opener.popitup(document.getElementById('newfirst').value,document.getElementById('newsecond').value);\">Send Mail</a></td></tr></table>");
      mywindow.document.write("</FORM>");
  }

  function popitup(user,key) {
      alert(''+user+'');
      alert(''+key+'');
      var url = 'http:\/\/localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/mailservlet?receiver=' + user + '&issue=' + key;
      newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=400,width=400');
      if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
  }
```

Issues fixed:
1) Escaping problem in window.open
2) function call should be opener.popitup
3) Id names for user and key were incorrect.

Comment: thanks it works great now. In fact your code uses better nested escape then mine.

Answer (score 0):

please dont do it like this (document write)

use appendChild, and append the onclick-handler there